# How do you tint/lighten a color in Sketch?

Tags: color, sketch-app, color-spaces

I can't figure out how to simply add white to a color in Sketch. In Illustrator this is as simple as making it a spot color and dragging the slider in the Color panel, but Sketch only lets you adjust RGBA and HSBA values.

Do I need to find a plugin to do this?

Comment: as a work-around, LAB colors allow you to adjust just lightness and this approximates what you want. So note that (HSB) S & B of 65 is approximately (LAB) 50 L. As you increase L, the S decreases and the B increases by nearly the same absolute value. So if you want to lighten by 5%, try adding 5 to B and subtracting 5 from S. This won't be exact, but may be good enough?

Comment: @Yorik That works within limits, but is definitely not exact and if my color starts with a B of 81 for example then I am very limited in how much lighter I can go. Right now I'm stuck with adding white or black layers on top with varying opacity. I'm continually amazed at the features Sketch chose to implement over basics like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this, depending on whether you want to be able to preserve the original color or not.

## Method 1: Use HSB

Click on the "R G B" label in the color picker, which will toggle the color picker between RGB and HSB:

[image: RGB Color Picker] [image: HSB Color Picker]

### Method 2: Add multiple fills

1. Click on the "+" button on fill to add a second fill.
   [image]
2. By default, Sketch will select this fill to be a gradient. Change this to solid.
   [image]
3. Select white as the color and adjust the opacity appropriately.
   [image]

The result is a lighter version of the color you started with. The advantage to this method is that your original color is preserved as a fill on the object, so it's easy to go back and adjust, and you can blend different colors other than white or even gradients. Note that you can also reorder the fills with drag and drop.

[image]

Comment: The multiple fills solution is ideal, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such an option for the moment.

The only way i found to do this is :

Select an objet with the base color, on a white background
[image]

Change shape opacity

[image]

Stay on your shape and use color picker to get the lighter color

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah this is what I do now, but it's far from ideal. I guess I gotta start learning the code for manipulating colors so I can make a plugin.