# How to creat a percentage of a color in Sketch

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, sketch-app

Illustrator has a feature that I find very useful to get a percentage of the color. Not by decreasing the opacity but mixing the color with white.

is it possible to do that in Sketch?

[image]

Comment: Hey Maira and welcome to GraphicDesign! Let us know if you have any questions about how the site works

Comment: related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/66380/how-do-you-tint-lighten-a-color-in-sketch

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one special switch, but you can add several colour fills to a specific layer. This should have the same effect. 
 [image: Sketch screenshot of colour panel]